# LWC Lightning-icon color is not changing using fill Css

Tags: lightning, slds, svg-icon

Not able to change the icon Color using Css.

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:arrowup" class="blueArrow" size="medium"></lightning-icon>
```

**CSS file**

```
.blueArrow {
    fill:blue;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Fill getting the default color.Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `lightning-icon` is an LWC, all its internals are protected within its own Shadow DOM. You cannot use CSS to impact its content directly. All you can do is use the properties specifically exposed on the component, and the closest to colour setting is the variant property. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/documentation) for details.

Fortunately, Salesforce added the ability to set CSS values through [Styling Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_custom_properties). As per the cited documentation, you define your CSS like:

```css
.blueArrow {
    --sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default: blue;
    --sds-c-icon-color-background: white;
}
```

or (for non-utility icons):

```css
.blueArrow {
    --sds-c-icon-color-foreground: blue;
    --sds-c-icon-color-background: white;
}
```